# Compute $\sum_{i=0}^{j} {\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}(j+1)!(1+i)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, summation

I am trying to figure out how to evaluate the following sum:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{j} {\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}(j+1)!(1+i)}$$

I have no idea how to proceed with this, but I really need to use it because it is part of the expression that I am trying to figure the closed form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the $(j+1)!$, because it is a constant:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=0}^j \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}(1+i) &= \sum_{i=1}^{j}\frac{(-1)^i}{(i-1)!} + \sum_{i=0}^{j}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\\
&= -\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!} + \sum_{i=0}^{j}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\\
&= \frac{(-1)^j}{j!}
\end{align}$$

Then multiply this by $(j+1)!$.